# Calling C functions within C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a medium length C file with a bunch of functions (NOT under a header file - just a bunch of functions), that I wish to gather and use under a C++ project I'm developing.

Now I've read about the `extern` function but I've only seen it work on small C functions that are under a .h file.

But I wish to include these functions without messing with the C files themselves since I don't really understand them - I just need the function "under the hood". Is there any easy simple solution to this problem?

Comment: Try to compile the c file with your c++ compiler. You may need to do some adaptions, but these should be minor and you probably should be able to do them without the need to fully understand the c code.

Comment: Having a medium length C file *without* any header file is suspicious. Why?

Comment: Give yourself a break, write a .h file for the .c file.  Then change the extension on the .c file to .cpp or wrapper the .c file with extern "c" { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need some `extern "C"` declarations visible in your C++ code:

```
extern "C" {
    int my_C_function_1(void);
    int my_C_function_2(void);
}
```

This can either go in a suitable header, or if it's only used within one particular .cpp file then you could just put it there.

Note that if your C functions are already declared within a C header somewhere you can just do this within your .cpp file:

```
extern "C" {
#include "my_C_header.h"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a C++ header file `myheader.hh`. It starts with

```
 #ifndef MYHEADER_INCLUDED
 #define MYHEADER_INCLUDED
 extern "C" {
```

then you declare all your public C functions, types, macros, etc.... At last you end it with

```
 }; // end extern C
 #endif MYHEADER_INCLUDED
```

In your C++ program, add `#include "myheader.hh"`

Alternatively (and instead of using `myheader.hh`), you might add (after other includes, but before C++ code) in your C++ file something like

```
extern "C") {
#include "your-C-code.c"
};
```

(But it might not work).

Comment: Why the downvote, since I'm telling exactly the same as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare the functions, typically in a header file, in order to call them from C++. If you compile these functions with a C compiler, then you will indeed need to surround the declarations with `extern "C"`; e.g.

```
extern "C" {
int foo(int, int);
}
```

If you have the source, then you could also modify it to include the header file (sans `extern "C"`) and compile the functions with your C++ compiler.

Comment: `compile the functions with your C++ compiler.` That would only work if the c code happens to be valid c++, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Certainly - depends on the C.